# How can I prevent ZF2 navigation from matching a page?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have this navigation config;

```
// Navigation
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
           'label' => '<i class="fa fa-user"></i> Users',
           'route' => 'cobalt/default',
            'controller' => 'user',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'New User',
                    'controller' => 'user',
                    'action' => 'add',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Edit',
                    'controller' => 'user',
                    'action' => 'edit',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Delete',
                    'controller' => 'user',
                    'action' => 'delete',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'label' => '<i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Admin',
            'route' => 'admin',
            'pages' => array(
                // Support Technicians.
                array(
                    'label' => 'Support Technicians',
                    'controller' => 'user',
                    'action' => 'technicians',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

When i navigate to user/technicians this correctly matches the support technicians page in navigation rendering my breadcrumb like;

```
Admin > Support Techicians
```

However because this route matches the user controller, both the Admin and User pages are set to active in my side navigation.

Is there a way I can prevent the User page being active?

Comment: tried $this->navigation('navigation')->findOneByController('user')->setActive(false); in my view script for technicians, but user page still renders as if active

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I needed to set the action on the user page to 'index'. Now it only matches as active if the action is index, or a child page is active.

```
    array(
       'label' => '<i class="fa fa-user"></i> Users',
       'route' => 'cobalt/default',
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action' => 'index' // <-- fix
        'pages' => array(
```